# android java get spinner selected string value

Tags: java, android, spinner

I want to display the String number from mySpinner only inside my Toast but I can't find out to do just that thing. Any help is welcome!

```
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{ id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String name = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    list.add(name + "\n" + number);
                    break;
                }

                pCur.close();
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;

    }
```

adapter stuff of no importance

```
    spinnerClickListener();


}
```

Onclick method for imagebutton to display the selected contact phone number in a toast.

```
public void spinnerClickListener(){
    //spinner item button onclick listener

    callBTN = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.call);
    mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.contacts);

    callBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected number :" + "\n" + mySpinner.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: where have you set adapter on spinner ?

Comment: above spinnerClickListener(); in onCreate

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        mySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);`

Comment: Spinner is doing fine, I only need to display the string number from SelectedItem in toast

Comment: you should add this code to actual question only.. and where are you adding data to this adapter ?

Comment: ok my bad you have passed `list`. What is the problem you exactly are facing ? in your toast you are getting a null value ?

Comment: `mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.contacts)`  you dont need to do this again. You should use same reference

Comment: No I only want to dispay number string in my toast. It displays all the info from spinner in toast and that is not what I want

Comment: in mySpinner.getSelectedItem() it displays the selected spinner value. But what I want is that it displays only the string number in toast.

Comment: It is much better to model data, and then put in ArrayList, then add it to spinner. Hence later you can reach selected item as an object and get Id from object. Can you do it this way?

Comment: To put all the data into strings.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```
mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

instead of

```
mySpinner.getSelectedItem()
```

Comment: I want to display the string number inside my toast from my spinner not from my spinner into a string.